# VBScript and Windows Shell. How to detect window events

Tags: vbscript, windows-shell

I have a situation where I have to detect when an application window is closed. I am currently just looking in the task manager to see if the app is running or not.

But now when the app window is closed I need to determine if this was an event caused by the user or another process.

So how can I hook into a window's event within a vbscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor when a program stops in VBScript using WMI.  That's pretty simple.  You can even set up an event-driven script that executes when it stops.  It looks like this:

```
strProcess = "someprocess.exe"

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 " _
        & "WHERE TargetInstance ISA CIM_Process " _
            & "AND TargetInstance.Name='" & strProcess & "'")

While True
    ' Process stopped
Wend

Set colEvents = Nothing
Set objWMIService = Nothing
```

The problem is that there is no way to detect *why* it stopped or what action caused it unless that specific program fires an event or writes to the event log (or any other log for that matter).  Sorry.